# How to get the `Twitter Media_ID` of shared video from my App..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I made one video and I am sharing it on Twitter and retrieving the count and retweet of that video.

> 1.Sharing video the using following code and on the  response.

I got the media ID from that media_ID I got the count,(15 days ago ) but  don't know what happen now. It's give an error

Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *returnedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]; 
mediaID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [returnedData valueForKey:@"media_id_string"]];
```

> ERROR: No status found with that ID.

Please help me out from these.

OR tell me if there are any changes in **Twitter documentation**.

Comment: Show the code you are using to try and retrieve the status. We can't help if we cant see what you are working with

Comment: I got the media_ID of this response but when I use that ID to get count it shows the Error,,,!!!

NSMutableDictionary *returnedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    me_ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [returnedData valueForKey:@"media_id_string"]];

//Get COUNT
[twitter getStatusesShowID:@"ID" trimUser:0 includeMyRetweet:0 includeEntities:0 useExtendedTweetMode:0 successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status){
 NSLog(@"statuses:%@",status);